# How to pass multiple HashMap<String,Integer> in BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

I Pass one HashMap in my listview BaseAdapter works perfectly.

When i pass three HashMap in my adapter it gives same value as before

How can i Pass multiple HashMap i don't know

Here is MyAdapter

**MyAdapter.java**

```
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final ArrayList mData;

    public MyAdapter(HashMap<String, Integer> name) {
        mData = new ArrayList();
        mData.addAll(name.entrySet());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<String, Integer> getItem(int position) {
        return (Map.Entry) mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO implement you own logic with ID
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {
            result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_order_list, parent, false);
        } else {
            result = convertView;
        }

        Map.Entry<String, Integer> item = getItem(position);
        String value = String.valueOf(item.getValue());

        // TODO replace findViewById by ViewHolder
        ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.Name)).setText(item.getKey());
        ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.Quantity)).setText(value);


        return result;
    }
}
```

Appreciate your Help Thanks in Advance

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: i wanna make a list view

Comment: what do you mean by this ? How can i Pass multiple Adapter i don't know!!

Comment: check below answer .

Answer (score 2):

> When i pass three HashMap in my adapter it gives same value as before

since you have not a method to add stuff to your dataset you are probably calling `new MyAdapter` three times, and passing the last instance to the your `ListView`. You probably want to add a method to add the new `HashMap`'s instance to `mData`, E.g.

```
 public void addItem(HashMap<String, Integer> item) {
    synchronized(mData) {
       mData.add(item)
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

and call it from the outside, using the `Adapte`r's instance